# How can I filter rows before and after in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this whol dataframe I have these flagged and unflagged rows, 
i want to filter out the rows before and after the flagged row and also need the flagged row to,

so my data is

```
index            DateTime       A1   A2   A4        AMS  ID          flCol
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
16610747    2011-01-03T13:15:59 112 103 368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
16610749    2011-01-03T13:17:00 95  90  368010037   128 003669730   flagged
16610751    2011-01-03T13:18:00 75  67  368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
16610753    2011-01-03T13:18:59 42  33  368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
16610755    2011-01-03T13:20:00 14  7   368010037   128 003669794   notflagged
```

and i need only like this way, the point before flagged one, after one, and the one which is flagged?

```
   16610747 2011-01-03T13:15:59 112 103 368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
   16610749 2011-01-03T13:17:00 95  90  368010037   128 003669730   flagged
   16610751 2011-01-03T13:18:00 75  67  368010037   128 003669730   notflagged
```

and I need the complete row in a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a `mask` with all the condition on the column 'flCol' and `shift` to look for the row before or after

```
mask = ( (df['flCol'] == 'flagged')|
         (df['flCol'].shift(1) == 'flagged')|
         (df['flCol'].shift(-1) == 'flagged') )
```

Then `df[mask]` should contains the data you want